# Populate a ListPicker with entries from an IsolatedStorage File

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, binding, listpicker, isolatedstoragefile

When the app is first ever run I write some defaults to a text file in IsolatedStorageFile, as below:

```
if (!settings.Contains("firstrun"))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();                                 // Use a StringBuilder to construct output.
                var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();           // Create a store
                store.CreateDirectory("testLocations");                                 // Create a directory
                IsolatedStorageFileStream rootFile = store.CreateFile("locations.txt"); // Create a file in the root.
                rootFile.Close();                                                       // Close File
                string[] filesInTheRoot = store.GetFileNames();                         // Store all files names in an array
                Debug.WriteLine(filesInTheRoot[0]);                                     // Show first file name retrieved (only one stored at the moment)

                string filePath = "locations.txt";

                if (store.FileExists(filePath)) {

                    Debug.WriteLine("Files Exists"); 
                    StreamWriter sw =
                            new StreamWriter(store.OpenFile(filePath,
                                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write));

                            Debug.WriteLine("Writing..."); 
                            sw.WriteLine("Chicago, IL");
                            sw.WriteLine("Chicago, IL (Q)");
                            sw.WriteLine("Dulles, VA");
                            sw.WriteLine("Dulles, VA (Q)");
                            sw.WriteLine("London, UK");
                            sw.WriteLine("London, UK (Q)");
                            sw.WriteLine("San Jose, CA");
                            sw.WriteLine("San Jose, CA (Q)");
                            Debug.WriteLine("Writing complete"); 

                        }
                }
```

This appears to work, but now I need to populate my ListPicker with the contents of this text file, in alphabetical order.

What is the best way to do that? Create a list from the text file and then populate the ListPicker with the list?

Comment: I suggest you to read/write with XmlSerializer using List<string>.

Comment: "What is the best way to do that? Create a list from the text file and then populate the ListPicker with the list?" yes, that way. @Mkrtich OP is not talking about XML, it is plain text file.

Comment: Thanks har07, I went that route as soon as I typed it and managed to get it to work. However, making it list the entries in alphabetical order may be more tricky.

Comment: Nothing tricky there. Just use the `.OrderBy()` extension method after you populate your list.

Comment: Thanks @Pantelis I'll give that try later on today. Appreciate all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @har07 for confirming my thinking. I launch a full screen ListPicker from a button like so:

```
private void locChoice(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            string filePath = "locations.txt";

            if (store.FileExists(filePath))
            { 
               Debug.WriteLine("Files Exists");
                try
                {
                    string fileData;
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream =
                        new IsolatedStorageFileStream("locations.txt", FileMode.Open, store))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(isoStream))
                        {
                            fileData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                    testLocationPicker.ItemsSource = fileData.Split(';');
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

            }

            testLocationPicker.Open();
        }
```

I will work on the ordering as per @Pantelis suggestion.